# Error on Xcode with React native Could not find autolink framework

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

when I try to build my app that works fine in android I run into an error:

> lib RNFirebase.a(RNFirebase AdMob.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you already tried to set `$(inherited)` in the **Other Linker Flags**? 
You can search this under 'build settings' of your project in Xcode.